# Big-O Hierarchy and comparisons

Tags: big-o

> Which are the corrent hierarchy  between above. is that correct?

```
0(n^3) < O(2^n) < O(n^2)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming

Comment: @apkos99, it's better to ask smarter questions. However, I will answer at least  guide you to understand the topic.

Comment: thank u...can you please me tell me the hierarchy between these two???
log((3n)!) and log(n^3)

Comment: the grapfs below doesnt contain factorial case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O(n^2)` is of a lower order than `O(n^3)`, which is of a lower order than `O(2^n`). Refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) for a table of common functions in order.

Answer (score 1):

There is a graph that can help you understand the common complexities.Please refer [here](http://science.slc.edu/~jmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/) to better understand the concepts.

http://science.slc.edu/~jmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/running-times.gif[image]